# how to duplicate pointer in order to point on the same object

Tags: c, pointers, struct, duplicates

I'm new with all the C programming and I have a question ,

If I have a struct for example - and I'm pointing on it , I want to create a new pointer in order to point on the same data , but not for the two pointers to point on the same object .
how can I do that without copying every single field in the struct ?

```
typedef struct
{
 int x;
 int y;
 int z;
}mySTRUCT;

mySTRUCT *a;
mySTRUCT *b;
a->x = 1;
a->y = 2;
a->z = 3;
```

and now I want b to point on the same data

```
b = *a
```

it's not correct, and the compiler is yelling at me

any help would be great! thank you :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First thing, you code is incorrect. You create a *pointer* named `a`, but you don't create anything for it to point to. You aren't allowed to dereference it (with `a->x`) until it points to something.

Once you actually have some structs for your pointers to point to, then you can copy them by assignment:

```
myStruct a_referand = {0};
myStruct b_referand = {0};
myStruct *a = &a_referand;
myStruct *b = &b_referand;

a->x = 1;
*b = *a; // copy the values of all members of a_referand to b_referand
// now b->x is 1
b->x = 2;
// now b->x is 2 but a->x is still 1
```

Comment: why is it *b = *a and not b = *a ? I can't understand the difference between  : b = a , *b = a , b = * a , *b = *a . can I get a short explanation please?

Comment: @user1386966: `a` and `b` are pointers. `*a` and `*b` are the things they point to. You want to copy the thing pointed to by `a`, across to the thing pointed to by `b`. Hence you write `*b = *a`. `b = a` changes the pointer `b` to have the same value as `a`, which is another way of saying change `b` to point to the same thing that `a` points to. `b = *a` and `*b = a` are meaningless, because you can't make a struct be equal to a pointer.

Comment: My usual analogy, btw, is that a pointer is like a piece of paper with a street address written on it. The thing it points to (aka "referand") is like a building. You wouldn't confuse a building (`*b)` with something that has the building's address written on it (`b`). `*b = *a` means "build a building at the address on `b`, and make it the same as the building whose address is on `a`". `b = a` means "copy the address written on `a` to `b`". The analogy slightly weakens when you note that in C you can take a pointer to `a` - even pieces of paper can have their own addresses in C.

Comment: thanks, it helps understanding that... after learning java , C seems to be realllly tricky

Comment: In Java you often don't need to think about the difference between an object vs a variable whose current value is that object. But the difference is still there, and the difference between `b = a` and `*b = *a` in C is the same as the difference in Java between `x = y` and `x.setTime(y.getTime())`, where `x` and `y` are variables of type `java.util.Date`. I use `Date` as the example only because it's the simplest mutable object type I could think of in the Java libraries.